# Как правильно остановить видео через событие popstate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, видео

Пытаюсь реализовать остановку или паузу видео когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку назад в браузере. Не знаю как правильно сделать, помогите.
Код который я сделал но он не работает:

```
addEventListener("popstate",function(e){
document.getElementById('#video').pause();
},false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
var state = e.originalEvent.state;
if (state !== null) {
$('#button').pause();  
}
});
```

или так:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
var state = e.state;
if (state !== null) {
  document.getElementById('video').pause();
}
});
```

кстати вы неправильно указали блок, # не нужно ставить в document.getElementById, может в этом ошибка)